How to link png or other sources from the scss in Typo3 12?
Typo3 12 moved all extensions to the vendor folder (so the /public folder form extensions is not public anymore) and created a hashed-named folder in the "_assets" folder for each extension so it is possible to do this:
.icon-metal-detection {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-image: url('/_assets/5f2f0b71dc3c27d2b89fdb263ae9883e/Icons/icon.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

BUT, will that folder name be changed in the future or from one typo3 installation to the other? (local, dev, staging, prod)
Also, how would I know this "hashed-named" for my extension there is no reference to know which one is which. Until now I have opened them one by one to know which one is the one I need but that's very impractical.
PD: Relative path wont work because typo3 is prepending ../../../ so if I do url('../Icons/icon.png'); it ends up being url('../../../../Icons/icon.png'); which will take nowhere.
Cheeers

The easiest way would be to make it relative to the scss/css file
.icon-metal-detection {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-image: url('../Icons/icon.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}


This will of course only work if the css and image is in the same extension.

This wont work because typo3 is prepending ../../../ so if I do url('../Icons/icon.png'); it ends up being url('../../../../Icons/icon.png'); which will take nowhere.
It prepends that because the vendor folder is not public so anything that you want to link you must do it from the root... so with ../../../ is trying to take you to the root folder of the project.
For the same reason is that this works:
url('/_assets/5f2f0b71dc3c27d2b89fdb263ae9883e/Icons/icon.png');
Because it prepends "../../../" so the link _assets starts from the root folder where _assets actually is.
